# Fill two dimensional list by meeting given conditions

Tags: calculation-puzzle

> Suppose you have a 2D array - a list that exits in both x and y axis - which is 4 x 4, and you need to fill the table by putting numbers in it obeying following restrictions.
>
> 1. Each cell is able to store a number that can be calculated according to its index. (Indexes start from [0,0])
>
>    If a cell's index is [i, j] it can store a number calculated as one of the following ways.
>
>    1. i x j + i - j
>    2. i x j + j - i
>    3. i ^ j
>    4. j ^ i
> 2. Each cell can carry at most multiplication of its adjacent cells. (horizonal  and vertical)
> 3. Each cell should be colored in a way all odds are of same color and all evens are of same color and two same colored cell cannot stand side by side vertically or horizontally.

Comment: How do you define $0^0$?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is

> Impossible

Reasoning

> The cell with index $[1,1]$ must contain the entry $ 1\times 1 + 1 - 1 = 1^1 = 1$. 
>  Now consider the cell with index $[0,1]$ which is adjacent to $[1,1]$. This must contain either 
>  (i) $0 \times 1 + 0 - 1 = -1$, 
>  (ii) $0 \times 1 + 1 - 0 = 1$ 
>  (iii) $0^1 = 0$ 
>  (iv) $1^0 = 1$ 
>  Now, (i), (ii) and (iv) are odd which would break rule 3. 
>  However if we are in case (iii) then we break rule 2, since the cell with index $[1,1]$ can carry, at most, multiplication of its adjacent cells, which would be $0$ in this case.

Comment: Actually it may be possible due to the fact that (according to the rules) rot13(rnpu pryy VF NOYR (be PNA) pbagnva n ahzore, ohg abg arprffnevyl FUBHYQ gb qb fb. Fbzr pryyf znl pbagnva ab ahzoref ng nyy (naq fb, abg orvat terngre guna nal bgure ahzoref, yvxr AnA va cebtenzzvat))

Comment: @trolley813 That's quite an interesting take. Wouldn't it contravene the sentence "...you need to fill the table by putting numbers in it obeying following restrictions." in the opening paragraph?

Comment: maybe, but you can fill the table partially. I'm now writing my "solution".

Answer (score 0):

My "solution" (a lateral thinking answer)

> `__0 NaN   1 NaN`
>   `NaN   1 NaN   1`
>   `__1 NaN   4 NaN`
>   `NaN   1 NaN   9`

Explanation

> `NaN` meaning [*not-a-number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) (according to the rules, a cell does not *has* to contain a number, but rather *can* do so). All other rules are obviously complied (if a cell contains a number, it is of the 4 permitted ones; NaNs (and their products) are never greater than any number; you should color all "odd" cells blue, "evens" green and NaNs grey, since the latter are neither even nor odd).